# how do I know what n(positive integer) is when user types ./a.out -n?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

How do I make an command line argument a variable?

That is, for example, how do I know what n(positive integer) is when user types ./a.out -n?

I know I can use `strcmp(argv[1], "-1")` `strcmp(argv[1], "-100")` but is there a simpler way to implement this?

Comment: Use http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-Getopt.html#Using-Getopt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

`strtol(argv[1])` or `atoi(argv[1])`

to get the integer no need to compare it as a string and see.

PS: atoi(NULL) will cause UB.

Check the code below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int n;
   if( argc >2)
   return 1;

   if(argv[1][0] == '-')
     n = atoi(argv[1] +1);
   else
      n= atoi(argv[1]);
   printf("%d\n",n);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping! but there is a '-' in argv[1] also, what do i do with that?

Comment: @JoeyZeng `-` is part of the string right that should be fine to get you a negative integer try printing `atoi("-12");`

Comment: I don't quiet understand what you are saying... when user types ./a.out -5, I only want to know what number he/she typed, which is 5...

Comment: @JoeyZeng Check the code in the edits. you need to check for the first character and if it is `-` then just ignore it and find the positive integer value of it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `-n` is a command line optional argument, It is always suggested using `getopt` or `Argp`, and use `case` to check if it its a positive integer.

Refer the following links for further information about using them http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html

For more information about command line arguments, the following link will help you http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/c/mike/misc/cmdline_args.html